# How to Update item values without changing the whole List?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, data-binding, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I'm working on a Grid RecyclerView for Scores App. Scores will be updated every 5 secs from API Call...

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter/) for my Recyclerview Adapter.

I'm using `Observable Fields & List`.

I need to update `only the scores (textviews)` but now the RecyclerView is getting updated every 5 secs.

Please Guide me in right direction. Thank you!

[Full Code in Gist](https://gist.github.com/drmkraja/975882b0612be60761489b26bcfc54c6)

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel
private lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding

lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit
lateinit var apiService: APIService
lateinit var disposable: Disposable

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
    fetchData()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil
        .inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    binding.viewModel = dashboardViewModel

    return binding.root
}

fun fetchData() {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()

    retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(APIService.BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()

    apiService = this.retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

    callIndicesEndpoint(null)

    disposable = Observable.interval(1000, 2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ aLong: Long? -> this.refreshIndices(aLong)})
        { throwable: Throwable -> this.onError(throwable) }
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
private fun callIndicesEndpoint(aLong: Long?) {
    val observable =
        apiService.indices
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map { result: ObservableArrayList<Indices> -> result }
        .subscribe(
            { data: ObservableArrayList<Indices> ->
                this.handleResults(data)
            }
        ) { t: Throwable ->
            this.handleError(t)
        }
}

@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
private fun refreshIndices(aLong: Long?) {
    val observable =
        apiService.indices
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map { result: ObservableArrayList<Indices> -> result }
        .subscribe({ data: ObservableArrayList<Indices> -> this.refreshResults(data)})
        { t: Throwable ->this.handleError(t)}
}

private fun handleResults(data: ObservableArrayList<Indices>) {
    dashboardViewModel.populate(data)
}


private fun refreshResults(data: ObservableArrayList<Indices>) {
    dashboardViewModel.refresh(data)
}

private fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
    Log.e(">>>", "ERROR")
}

private fun handleError(t: Throwable) {
    Log.e("> >", t.localizedMessage + " - Err - " + t.cause)
    //Add your error here.
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    disposable.dispose()
}
 }
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel() {

val indices: ObservableList<Indices> = ObservableArrayList<Indices>()

fun populate(data: ArrayList<Indices>) {
    indices.clear()
    indices.addAll(data)
}

fun refresh(data: ArrayList<Indices>) {
    // How to refresh only Items without recreating the List
}

val itemIds: ItemIds<Any> =
    ItemIds { position, item -> position.toLong() }

val indicesItem: ItemBinding<Indices> =
    ItemBinding.of<Indices>(BR.item, R.layout.item_futures)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver functionality for update particular items from recyclerview .

Comment: explain please. Its a bounty question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use `DiffUtil`, it'll be of great help as

> DiffUtil figures out what has changed, RecyclerView can use that information to update only the items that were changed, added, removed, or moved, which is much more efficient than redoing the entire list.

Here is a course you can use to get a hand of it: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding/#3

Answer (score 0):

When I had something like that I used the DiffUtil.

I had to update rates every X seconds and not change the whole list.

So the adapter should be something like this:

```
class RatesAdapter :
ListAdapter<Rate, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(RateDiffCallback()) {
private val baseRateView = 0
private val rateView = 1
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return if (viewType == rateView) {
        RateHolder(
            RateItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
            )
        )
    } else {
        BaseRateHolder(
            BaseRateLayoutBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false
            )
        )
    }
}


override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (position == 0) {
        baseRateView
    } else rateView
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val rate = getItem(position)
    if (holder.itemViewType == rateView) {
        (holder as RateHolder).bind(rate)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            swapper.itemSwap(rate)
        }
    } else {
        (holder as BaseRateHolder).bind(rate)
    }
}

class RateHolder(
    private val binding: RateItemBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(item: Rate) {
        binding.apply {
            rate = item
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }


}

class BaseRateHolder(
    private val binding: BaseRateLayoutBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(item: Rate) {
        binding.apply {
            rate = item
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    val value = binding.value
}
}

private class RateDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Rate>() {


override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Rate, newItem: Rate): Boolean {
    return oldItem.currencyCode == newItem.currencyCode
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Rate, newItem: Rate): Boolean {
    return oldItem.rate == newItem.rate
}

}
```

Here I used binding in the adapter, and if you are not familiar with it, I will be more than happy to explain as well

In the Activity: 
Before the onCreate:

```
private val ratesAdapter = RatesAdapter()
```

In the onCreate:

```
ratesList.adapter = ratesAdapter
```

Whenever you need to update the adapter including the first time you need to call it:

```
ratesAdapter.submitList(rates)
```

**Rate** is the model class that I am using
**rates** is the mutable list of < Rate >
**ratesList** is the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

try this : [notifyItemChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object))

with this:

```
listView.setItemAnimator(null);
```